# High current and voltage DPDT switch

Tags: switches

I have two different voltage sources that can supply a LR load. I need a mechanical DPDT switch that can be used to choose the voltage source. When used properly the switching between sources would occur when neither voltage source is on. One source can supply up to 200A at 100V continuously at frequencies between 1000-5000 Hz whereas the other source supplies short bursts (approximately 250 us) at as much as 8 kA. Here is my two part question:

(1) If the switch is made when neither source is on (proper use) then I suspect that the current and voltage ratings (or maybe just the voltage rating) of the switch isn't very important. I would think that as long as the conductors within the switch are as thick as the wire carrying the current then it will work safely (as far as the hardware is concerned). Is this correct?

(2) However, I should probably consider using a switch that will be safe even if the switch is thrown improperly (ie. thrown when the 200A - 100V source is on) in which case the current and voltage becomes important for safety reasons. What type of switch should I use? A knife blade is simple but not particularly safe for the operator of the switch.

Thanks!

Comment: 1)no 2) a safety breaker

Comment: 8kA? Your going to need some big big wires and contacts for that.

Comment: The wires aren't abnormally thick (don't remember the gauge). At 8KA the source is only on very briefly (250 microsec).

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy. Why "no" to question 1?

Comment: 200A at 100V is like a welder, switching that is going to be hard